# Show that given $ϵ>0,$ there exists $x∈X$ such that $∥x∥=1$ and $d(x,M)>1−ϵ.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $M$ be a proper closed linear subspace of $X$. Show that given $ϵ>0,$ there exists $x∈X$ such that $∥x∥=1$ and $d(x,M)>1−ϵ.$

My Work:

Let $ ϵ>0$. Since M is closed and proper $∃x_0∈X−M$ such that $d(x_0,M)=inf\{∥x_0−m∥:m∈M\}>0.$ Let $η=d(x_0,M)$. Then $∃m′∈M$ such that $∥x_0−m′∥<η+ϵ.$

Now let $\displaystyle x=\frac{(x_0−m′)}{∥(x_0−m′)∥}.$ Then $x∈X$ and $∥x∥=1$. Hence, $∥x_0−x∥≥1−∥x_0∥.$ Now, $∥x_0−x∥=∥x_0−m′+m′−x∥≤∥x_0−m′∥+∥m′−x∥<η+ϵ+∥x−m′∥$. So we have $1−∥x_0∥<η+ϵ+∥x−m′∥.$

After that I was stuck. If I can show that $∥x−m′∥>1−ϵ$ then I am done. Can somebody please help me to complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to assume $\epsilon<1$ as you have demonstrated if $\epsilon>1$, then $\dfrac{x}{||x||}$ will suffice. Now take $1-\epsilon<1$, so $\dfrac{1}{1-\epsilon}>1$, so $\dfrac{||x-M||}{1-\epsilon}>||x-M||$. By definition of $||x-M||$, there is a $y\in M$ such that $0<||x-M||\leq||x-y||<\dfrac{||x-M||}{1-\epsilon}$. Now take $z=\dfrac{(x-y)}{||x-y||}$. Then $||z||=1$ and $||z-M||=\dfrac{||x-M||}{||x-y||}>1-\epsilon$ by cross multiplying.